# MVVM - Validation on a Property inside the View Model

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, mvvm

I'm trying to get custom validation working for my property inside the view model, although it doesn't seem to be hitting my break point in the validation logic. I'm using another validation I made earlier(which I used in my model and it worked) to try and enter the validation logic so I can customize it to my needs

**Validation:**

```
    [Required]
    [CustomValidation(typeof(CardRangeValidator), "CrossValidateFirstWithLast")]
```

**Property:**

```
    public const string ExpiresOnPropertyName = "ExpiresOn";

    private DateTime? expiresOn = DateTime.Today.AddYears(1);

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the ExpiresOn property.
    /// TODO Update documentation:
    /// Changes to that property's value raise the PropertyChanged event. 
    /// This property's value is broadcasted by the Messenger's default instance when it changes.
    /// </summary>
    public DateTime? ExpiresOn
    {
        get
        {
            return expiresOn;
        }

        set
        {
            if (expiresOn == value)
            {
                return;
            }

            expiresOn = value;

            RaisePropertyChanged(ExpiresOnPropertyName);
        }
    }
```

**Validation Logic:**

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace Fsc.Feenics.Clients.Silverlight2.Web.Models.Shared
{
public class CardRangeValidator
{
    public static ValidationResult CrossValidateFirstWithLast(int number,     ValidationContext context)
    {
        var cardRangeInfo = context.ObjectInstance as CardRangeInfo;
        if (cardRangeInfo == null) return ValidationResult.Success;
        return ValidateFirstLessThanLast(number, cardRangeInfo.Last);
    }

    public static ValidationResult CrossValidateLastWithFirst(int number, ValidationContext context)
    {
        var cardRangeInfo = context.ObjectInstance as CardRangeInfo;
        if (cardRangeInfo == null) return ValidationResult.Success;
        return ValidateFirstLessThanLast(cardRangeInfo.First, number);
    }

    private static ValidationResult ValidateFirstLessThanLast(int firstNumber, int lastNumber)
    {
        return firstNumber <= lastNumber ? ValidationResult.Success : new ValidationResult("First number in range must be less than or equal to last number in range", new string[] { "First", "Last" });
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't RaisePropertyChanged(ExpiresOnPropertyName) be using ExpiresOn instead?

Comment: Im assuming that this is something a user needs to fill in.  Is this true?  Is there XAML that this property is bound to?  Please include.

Comment: it will be more helpful if you paste your xml code also.